# Populate fields in T-SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

This is my view:

[image]

The view has two difference voucher `2PI1700116` and `2PI1700117`.At least, one row of vouchers will have a vendor. I want to fill all empty fields in the **vendor** fields with the one that exists at least once.If it was another language, I would use a dictionary and then loop it. But I do not want to use **UPDATE**.

The result should return all columns.

Comment: Which view? Btw, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? SQL Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using SQL server, to get result where vendor will befilled in every row, you could use `MAX` window function (which will return vendor if it exists for particular ID):

```
select Voucher,
       max(Vendor) over (partition by Voucher) Vendor,
       Amount,
       --some more columns
from my_table
```